# continuous map theorem and convergence rate

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I know that if a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$
and a sequence of random variables $Y_n$ converges in probability to $Y$
then, by the continuous map theorem the sequence $(X_n-Y_n)^2$ converges in probability to $(X-Y)^2$.
But can I use this theorem somehow also in the manner of preserving the rate of the convergence of the sequences? i.e I know the rate of convergence of $X_n$ to $X$ and of $Y_n$ to $Y$, and I want to understand the rate of convergence of $(X_n-Y_n)^2$ to $(X-Y)^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "rate of convergence"?

Comment: Meaning I know Pr(Xn−X>ε1)≤k and Pr(Yn−Y>ε2)≤s (k and s are some constants dependent on n and ε), and I want to find Pr((Xn-Yn)^2-(X-Y)^2>ε3)≤?